# Do I need to modify httpd.conf to get symfony to wor

Tags: symfony1

Can someone tell me is it necessary to modify httpd.conf to get symfony to work? I am following a tutorial which says I need to edit httpd.conf file but my provider does not give me access to that file.

**from tutrial: http://www.symfony-project.org/cookbook/1_2/en/web_server**

> Alias
>
> If you already have a website on a
> domain name, and if you wish that your
> symfony application can be accessed
> within this domain, then the virtual
> host solution cannot work. For
> instance, let's assume that you want
> to access our symfony application
> with:
>
> To do that, open the httpd.conf and
> add the following lines:

```
Alias /myapp/
Alias /myapp/ /home/steve/myproject/web/
<Directory "/home/steve/myproject/web">
   AllowOverride All
   Allow from All
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can install symfony without access to http.conf. If your provider lets you choose the directory of the web root, choose yourapp/web directory. If the root directory is fixed, then make it a link to yourapp/web . If you want to have access to the images of the development bar (that normaly is not needed in production), then place a link in web/sf to lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf.